# Пауза перед отправкой ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, settimeout

Делаю поиск по базе при каждой введенной букве. Но что бы снизить нагрузку и избавится от частых запросов, нужно перед отправкой ajax отсчитать например 1-2 секунды и если в это время пользователь больше ничего не вводил, то отправляем запрос. А если вводил, то нужно опять отсчитать 1-2 секунды и только потом отправить запрос.

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#city_search input", function(){
    var word = $(this).val();
    setTimeout(function(){
        // отправляем ajax запрос
    }, 1000)
})
```

Куда можно добавить stop() что бы прекратить отправку и отсчитать заново 1-2 секунды? У многих сайтов так работает поиск.

Или это уже делается в PHP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var timer = null;
$(document).on("keyup", "#city_search input", function(){
    var word = $(this).val();
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        timer = null; 
        // отправляем ajax запрос
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.